# Why time per step continuously decreasing with increasing in number of epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

While training deep learning model, with every increase in number of epoch, the time taken to complete one step is continuously decreasing. What made this increase in efficiency as the data are same?

And why in first epoch, it very large as compare to other epochs? Any answer or reference for the same will be appreciable.

Here is my training model screenshot:

[image]

You can see the time/step is decreasing as 3s/step,810ms/step, 722ms/step and so on..

Comment: What are you using to train? `tf.data` possibly? Where are you running it? Does the same trend pertains for next epochs (or all `20`) or it starts fluctuating?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

The first epoch is slower due to a variety of initialization overhead: your entire model initializes to the selected values or distributions, the model layers are instantiated, etc.

Later epochs may accelerate for any of a variety of reasons.  The most common, in the work I do, is that various algorithmic analyzers are learning the data+flow control of your model, and are adjusting the flow for better performance.

This can involve input ingestion (caching), operation short-circuiting, switching to sparse-matrix computations as kernel weights "shake out" to have a majority oof 0.0 elements, etc.

However, without a proper example to accurately reproduce the effect, and no attempt to profile the execution, these ideas are only conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

This is very case specific and can not be generalized. Time taken is a variable component and is dependent on various external factors as well like memory availability during the course of run, input sizes etc.